# Indy Query Using Delphi

Tags: sockets, tcp, pascal, indy, delphi-xe

I have two `TIdTCPClient` components (TCPClient1 and TCPClient2) that share the same `OnStatus` property (see below).

The components are identified by their `Tag` property. How do I identify the calling TCPClient in the shared `OnStatus` event?

```pascal
procedure TForm2.TCPClientStatus(ASender: TObject; const AStatus: TIdStatus;
  const AStatusText: string);
begin
end;
```

Comment: I belive ASender parameter would hold the TidTCPClient instance. So something like this should work: if TIdTCPClient(ASender).Tag = 1 then ...

Answer (score 1):

The `ASender` parameter points to the object that is firing the event.  For a `TIdTCPClient`, that sender can be *either*:

- the `TIdTCPClient` object itself
- the client's `IOHandler` object

In the latter case, the `TIdTCPClient.OnStatus` event is hooked up to the `IOHandler` object *only if* that object is created *implicitly* within the client's `Connect()` method when the `IOHandler` property is `nil`.  In that scenario, the `TIdTCPClient` is set as the `Owner` of that new object.  On the other hand, if you *explicitly* assign your own `TIdIOHandler`-derived component to the `IOHandler` property before calling `Connect()`, the `TIdTCPClient.OnStatus` event will not be hooked up to the `IOHandler` component automatically, so you will have to assign a handler to that component's own `OnStatus` event separately, if needed.

So, inside of your `TIdTCPClient.OnStatus` event handler, assuming an *implicit* `IOHandler` object is being used, you can get back to the `TIdTCPClient` object like this:

```pascal
procedure TForm2.TCPClientStatus(ASender: TObject; const AStatus: TIdStatus;
  const AStatusText: string);
var
  Client: TIdTCPClient;
  IO: TIdIOHandler;
begin
  Client := nil;
  if ASender is TIdTCPClient then begin
    Client := TIdTCPClient(ASender);
  end
  else if ASender is TIdIOHandler then begin
    IO := TIdIOHandler(ASender);
    if IO.Owner is TIdTCPClient then
      Client := TIdTCPClient(IO.Owner);
  end;
  if Client <> nil then begin
    // use Client.Tag as needed...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The sender must not be a TIdTCPClient as I am getting an invalid typecast error.

Answer (score 1):

In all event handlers, in every component, the `Sender` argument is always the object instance which is triggering the event.

To get a hand on that object, you can do a simple cast or a safe cast. In the case of the `TIdTCPClient` you use and the `Tag` property you want to check, it would become:

```
TIdTCPClient(Sender).Tag
```

or

```
(Sender as TIdTCPClient).Tag
```

The second form is safer because if, for any reason, `Sender` is not of the assumed type, you'll get an exception at runtime that you can manage/detect using a `try/except` construct.

You can even share the same event handler between different kinds of components. I don't know Indy enough to give a related example, so I'll use the `OnClick` event for a `TButton` and a `TEdit`. You can use the `is` operator to check the type:

```
if Sender is TButton then
  // Do something using TButton(Sender).SomeProperty
else if Sender is TEdit then
  // Do something using TEdit(Sender).SomeProperty
```